# How do you do a require and a function in coffescript together?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I need to do this:

```
require('./config/enviroment.js')(app, express);
```

But i don't know the way to do..

i tried:

```
require './config/routes.js'(app, routes) ->
```

And i get

```
require('./config/routes.js'(app, routes)(function() {}));
```

But i think that is not what i'm looking.

I tried this too

```
require './config/enviroment.js'(app, express)
```

But i get

```
  require('./config/enviroment.js'(app, express));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to call a function that is the return value of another function:

```
f(args1) args2
f(args1)(args2)
(f args1) args2
(f args1)(args2)
```

So in your specific case:

```
require('./config/enviroment.js') app, express
require('./config/enviroment.js')(app, express)
(require './config/enviroment.js') app, express
(require './config/enviroment.js')(app, express)
```

Comment: so all i have to do is in the normal js way... ok ty ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can do exactly that.

Coffeescript:

```
 env = require('./config/enviroment.js')(app, express)
```

Compiles to:

```
 var env;
 env = require('./config/enviroment.js')(app, express);
```

Remember its just Javascript.

Comment: this one is correct 2 but i don't need (in this case) to save in a var, si i put the other one as correct.

Comment: I just added it so that the results from compiling would be clearer.